# HAProxy breaks HTTP request

Tags: apache-2.4, http

I'm not really sure what's going on here. I made a little internet of things thing a while back which builds HTTP requests that look like:

```
POST /update.py HTTP/1.1
Host: iot.example.com
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: [...]

iv=[...]&msg=base64(encrypted_msg)
```

And a corresponding server side python script which extracted information from the POST data. I recently changed my firewall's reverse proxy from squid to HAProxy and suddenly Apache is returning `HTTP 400` statuses, seeminly before the IOT device even gets a chance to send the POST data. Here's a wireshark TCP stream of one of these interactions:

```
POST /update.py HTTP/1.1
Host: iot.example.com
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 100
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-For: xx.xx.xx.xx

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sat, 17 Jun 2017 22:29:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (FreeBSD) mod_wsgi/4.5.15 Python/2.7
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
iv=En98cormFMA7NO5e-4qh2Q==&msg=ek_JDRJPqPUvNlztUVH6FTtfVVdHgODWMimBcZklos2XntlMOM1RweBjsp5z-zY=
```

- Note: Everything between the `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` and `</html>` are server replies, everything else is what the server is receiving. The X-Forwarded* headers were set by HAProxy. As far as I know Squid didn't use these

The really weird thing here is that Apache is responding even before it gets the POST data. The server responds fine to `GET` requests, and I'm running some other Apache servers behind the same firewall which all seem to work. The only real difference I can think of is that these HTTP requests are pretty much hard-coded to the microcontroller they're coming from, and maybe they aren't quite right to begin with. Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was the line endings in my HTTP requests. I was sending a mixture of LF and CRLF. [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2) requires that HTTP/1.1 only use CRLF, but also states that [servers should implement a "tolerance provision"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.3). However, Apache >= 2.4.25 defaults to `HttpProtocolOptions Strict` which returns a `HTTP/1.1 400` status to all malformed headers.

FreeBSD has packaged Apache 2.4.25 since December, but I assume Squid was regularizing headers for me because it didn't break then. I guess HAProxy is more laissez-fare, so the change from Squid to HAProxy exposed the server to my old firmware bug.

The right fix would be to re-flash the microcontroller with patched firmware, but that's a hassle. A quick and dirty workaround is to tell Apache to relax. Adding `HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe` to `httpd.conf` is a quick "fix" and at least gets the data logging back up and running for now.